# Wait for an element to be present or return false

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

It is possible to wait until an element is present on a page with `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id("button"))), 5000, "button not found")`

This will throw an error when the element is not found on the page. I do not want this function to throw an error, instead it should return `false` if the element is not found after 5 seconds.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you can attempt to achieve this is by using standard try/catch's. This will catch the exception that is produced from the browser.wait and handle it in the catch.

```
try{
   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id("button"))), 5000, "button not found")
}catch(){
   return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using if else block around with isdisplayed() function like

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(noRecordId)).isDisplayed()){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

you can use boolean variable in place of return to save result.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me, because at first I have to wait some time (5 seconds) before returning if the element is present on the site.

Comment: Then you can use `thread.sleep(5000)` before if anything doesn't work. **(Not Recommended)**